# Java Window Control

Tags: java, window, controls, reset

Not sure exactly how to word this, but I have created a BlackJack game that works. The dealer and User are delt two cards, you can hit or stay, it works fine. However, after the hand ends I want to display a window saying would you like to play again. If they click yes than the game will reset. I have already created this rest method but the only way I could get it to reset the current window the game is in is with a reset button within the game. Is there a way to have the pop up reset the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have written a Swing GUI (you don't say), I think that you want to look into using a JOptionPane as this will open as a modal dialog forcing the user to deal with the dialog before allowing him to interact with any other portion of the program.

Comment: Yes it is a Swing GUI sorry about that. Just looked it up and implemented it, finally works how I want it to. Thank you for the quick response and help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JOptionPane and switch on the return value. If `YES_OPTION`, call `resetGame()`. Otherwise, close the game or the take the appropriate action.

```
int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
    "Would you like to play another game?", "New Hand", 
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

switch (choice) {
  case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
    resetGame();
    break;
  case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
    closeGame();
    break;
  case JOptionPane.CLOSE_OPTION;
    closeGame();
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will be using this.